# Testing angularjs' factory with Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I've written a Factory with AngularJs which have a method that returns an http promise.

```
'use strict'

angular.module('projDefinitApp')
.factory 'testService', ($http) ->
  {  getTest: (testID) ->
    $http.get "temp/test.json"
  }
```

I'm having some issues when making a test, using karma and Jasmine. The promise didn't return any result. I tried to create a var, then call the function and change the value of the var. But it does not updates the value:

```
'use strict'
describe 'Service: testService', ->
  # load the service's module
  beforeEach module 'projDefinitApp'

  # instantiate service
  testService = {}
  beforeEach inject (_testService_) ->
    testService = _testService_

  it 'should do something', ->
    retrieved = undefined
    testService.getTest().success ($data,retrieved) ->
      retrieved = $data
      return
    expect(retrieved).toBe(null)
    return
  return
```

The console exit looks like this

> PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux) Service: testService should do something FAILED
>
> Expected undefined to be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in tests, Angular does not immediately perform requests made by the `$http` service. The reason being that all requests are queued up to be run in the `$digest` phase of the Angular lifecycle. You will need to run through Angular’s digest cycle manually in tests by calling `$rootScope.$apply()` or `$httpBackend.flush()` which will make the call internally.

One issue I see in the current test is that the tests aren’t made to work asynchronously, there is no guarantee that `retrieved` will be set before the expectation is called since the promises are resolved asynchronously. You rewrite the tests to make it work asynchronously:

```
it 'should do something', (done) ->
  testService.getTest().success ($data) ->
    expect($data).toBe(null)
    done()
    return

  $rootScope.$apply()
  return
return
```

Comment: That seems to work better, but keeps not working... If I do not make a mock (using httpbackend) the callback is never called. This error is shown "Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL"
The code entered is the same above in your example

Comment: @fernandezr sorry I missed the `$rootScope.$apply()` part of the code, look at the example again. As I mentioned before, you can also use `$httpBackend.flush()` if `$httpBackend` is already available in the test.

Comment: The code avobe works, but it starts making GET petitions to other places not only "temp/test.json". I also see that using $httpbackend this mocks the GET petition, but I would like that if I call to getTest, the method make the get petition itself, without need of mocking. Is this possible?

Comment: you will need to use `$httpBackend.when(…).passThrough()` which will allow the request to be made. If there are other requests being made, it is likely coming from either the instantiation of the module or the service, or possibly the requests could have been leaked from a previous test, I am afraid I can’t help you any more than that.